# How can I get Forest Tears?

Tags: danmachi-memoria-freese

Forest Tears are required in order to craft Forest's Teardrop, Lefiya's weapon.

How can these Forest Tears be obtained?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get the currency to exchange them from defeating specific monsters in Rampage. They appear during stages of Rampage- called 'irregular' though as far as I can tell they come quite randomly (but floor 15-17 on hard seems to have an increased chance of encountering them). I think you get either the gem currency or rare mats when you defeat them. To exchange them for special mats for character specific weapons is in the shop under 'special exchange'. I'm not sure if months have anything to do with it though o.o

Answer (score 0):

Don't think they're available yet, I'm on the last battle of 19~20 on very hard and I have yet to see one. I'll update my answer if I get one tomorrow after I heal up.

Answer (score 0):

It's month specific. So it won't be available during this month's rampage. For example, you see that the material for desperate is available only this month.